# Ближайшая метка на яндекс карте (конструктор)

Tags: javascript, yandex-maps-api

Есть карта с некоторым количеством объектов (меток) на карте, созданной в конструкторе карт. 
вопрос - как выводить адрес ближайшей метки с описанием пользователю (адрес + название метки) в div сбоку? 
через JS или как? пните в какую сторону копать

Comment: Копайте в эту сторону https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/jsbox/2.0/find_closest_object

Comment: @A1essandro Спасибо!